# Graph of a smooth map is a smooth manifold but is it orientabl

Tags: differential-topology

I got to know that the Tangent Bundle of a smooth manifold is Orientable
I read that the graph of a smooth map is a smooth manifold. Now I am thinking if it is always orientable or not.

I think it is not.

Define some map $f:U \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\Gamma_f=\{(x,y),f(x,y)) |(x,y)\in U \subset \mathbb{R}^2\}$$ gives us the Mobius strip, but I am not sure if I can find such a smooth function.  But I feel it need not be a orientable manifold in general.

Comment: The graph is diffeomorphic to the domain. Do you see why? Dose that answer the question?

Comment: yeah,  and morever ws have a global cover sending $((x,y),f(x,y)) \to (x,y)$ and so the Jacobian is identity. So it must be orientable.

Comment: Maybe you want a more interesting domain and codomain?

Comment: @TedShifrin, couldn't get you.